# I'm making an rss reader and would like to display pictures from an article if there are any. How do I go about getting those pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, json, rss, png

I'm new to web development and have started using JSONP and Google's Feed API to get the RSS articles using client side javascript.  If I must gather the photos from my server that's alright but doing it on the client side is preferable.  I have absolutely no idea how to get the relevant photo to an article.  I hope its not as bad as having to download the web page's html and looking for gif and png links.

Any helps is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the images might be returned in the RSS feed itself, and you just have to run through the feed looking for images to paste out.

If they don't include the images in the feed then you are going to have to download the page and look for the links to images.

Comment: I've never seen an RSS feed that attempts to include images within the feed. I don't even think that's possible.